# How can I convert string to list without '[ ]' and ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
Revenue = [400000000,10000000,10000000000,10000000]
s1 = []

for x in Revenue:
    message = (','.join(['{:,.0f}'.format(x)]).split())
    s1.append(message)
print(s1)

The output I am getting is something like this [['400,000,000'], ['10,000,000'], ['10,000,000,000'], ['10,000,000']] and I  want it should be like this -> [400,000,000, 10,000,000, 10,000,000,000, 10,000,000]
```

Can someone please help me on this, I am new to python

Comment: `[400,000,000, 10,000,000, 10,000,000,000, 10,000,000]` isn't a valid syntax in python. Commas are used to separate elements. You can surely print them as you want but can't have it in a list as type `int`

Comment: The digit separator in Python is `_`, not `,`. E.g. `10_000_000` for ten million, not `10,000,000`, which means `(10, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to just add in the commas you will be stuck with the `' '` due to the fact its going to be a `str` but you can eliminate that nesting by using a simpler *list comprehension*

```
Revenue = [400000000,10000000,10000000000,10000000]
l = ['{:,}'.format(i) for i in Revenue]
# ['400,000,000', '10,000,000', '10,000,000,000', '10,000,000']
```

You could also unpack the list into variables and then print each variable without `quotes`

```
v, w, x, y = l
print(v)
# 400,000,000
```

You can `print` the unpacked list but that will just be output

```
print(*l)
# 400,000,000 10,000,000 10,000,000,000 10,000,000
```

Expanded Loop:

```
l = []
for i in Revenue:
    l.append('{:,}'.format(i))
```

Comment: The OP wants `'400,000,000'` without `' '` which is not a valid python syntax

Comment: @Bazingaa  Yeah I mentioned that but I just thought as well, we can unpack and print and get that but it will just be output not variables

Comment: @Bazingaa I'm not sure why you are focused on valid python syntax: the question is about formatting output.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Well, from the OP's code it is clear that he/she is trying to append the values in this comma format to a list. Moreover if you read his/her complete desired output, you will see that he/she wants comma separated values in a list. So clearly the OP is not aware that this isn't possible. Printing values is a different issue. Everything what OP's code shows and what OP's desired output shows clearly makes it a syntax issue which needs to be conveyed to the OP.

Comment: @Bazingaa I agree with you on the invalidity of OP request, and just was trying to provide alternate solutions that are viable that maybe would be handy to OP or they could achieve some goal with

Comment: @vash_the_stampede: Your solutions are perfectly fine. The OP needs to be clear in his/her question. That's why I mentioned the syntax thing. Perhaps it will make him/her realize that the question needs to be edited or asked more clearly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want the output you've shown, because it is hard to read, but here is how to make it:

```
>>> Revenue = [400000000,10000000,10000000000,10000000]
>>> def revenue_formatted(rev):
...     return "[" + ", ".join("{:,d}".format(n) for n in rev) + "]"
...
>>> print(revenue_formatted(Revenue))
[400,000,000, 10,000,000, 10,000,000,000, 10,000,000]
```